# Mootools : inject a span into each list item of an UL

Tags: mootools, element, new-operator, inject

I am trying to inject a span into each list item of an UL which is the only UL in the div with the id of mydiv. The below code is only injecting into the last list item. But the consol log is writing for each list item. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? thanx for your time.

```
var myspan = new Element('span', { 'class': 'myspan' });
   $$('#mydiv ul li').each(function(el) {
       myspan.inject(el);
       console.log('the span has been injected');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is injecting in all, not just the last. it then moves it with each iteration - inject changes the parent node so it goes through all li's and ends up in the last one. you need to clone the span element:

```
var myspan = new Element('span', { 'class': 'myspan' });
$$('#mydiv ul li').each(function(el) {
    myspan.clone().inject(el);
    console.log('the span has been injected');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Dimitar, This is of course the solution. Didn't see the clone issue.